# Puppeteer wait for url

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have headless off and I want to wait untill user redirect to some page. I could use `waitForRequest` from puppeteer API but I don't know exact url it just must pass few circumstances.

So I use waitForFunction and check circumstances there but when I redirect to correct URL then I need to refresh page to pass circumstances for some reason.

My code is:

```
try {
    await page.waitForFunction(() => {
        if(window &&
           window.location &&
           window.location.hostname) {
            const host = window.location.hostname.split('.');
            if(!host.includes('www') &&
               !host.includes('new') &&
               host.includes('margonem') &&
               host.length === 3) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }, {
        polling: 200,
        timeout: 0
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

and when I redirect to URL which pass all of above if's then I need to reload page to actually see that it return true. Why it works like this? I don't want user to be forced to refresh page after he enter correct one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have headless off and I want to wait untill user redirect to some page.

just use [waitForNavigation()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions).

In combination with a `click` make sure you use [this pattern](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options):

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions),
  page.click(selector, clickOptions),
]);
```

`waitForNavigation` also returns a response object that you can then inspect

> I could use waitForRequest from puppeteer API but I don't know exact url it just must pass few circumstances.

in this case puppeteer injects the request as argument and you can just test this in your lambda function. For example:

```
page.waitForRequest(request => {
  return  request.url().includes('margonem') && request.method() === 'GET'
})
```

Comment: But waitForNavigation can take only `load,domcontentloaded,networkidle0,networkidle2` I want to wait for URL which would pass every if from my function. Did you read my question?

Comment: You wrote: "I want to wait untill user redirect to some page." in this case use waitForNavigation. but to clarify your other question, I updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but after that I specified what URL it has to be. Anyways I didn't know that you can pass function to waitForRequest. I think it'll solve my problem. Give me a second to try it out

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way I have found is using waitForFunction, it is simple to modify to fit your specifications as well as compact.

```
  await page.waitForFunction("window.location.pathname == '/Welcome.aspx'")
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes we need to wait until we reach a specific URL.

The best way to handle it is

```
    let holdProgress = true;
        while (holdProgress) {
            await page.waitFor(300);
            if (page.url().includes('/env-selector')) {
                holdProgress = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to ignore unwanted navigations until it matches your desired url. This one could help:

```js
while (true) {
  try {
    await page.waitForNavigation({
      timeout: 0,
    });

    await page.waitForFunction("window.location.pathname == 'blank'");

    break;
  } catch (error) {
    continue;
  }
}
```